# Visual Basic.NET code editor pretty listing auto ByVal

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

Enabling "Pretty listing" in Visual Studio 2010 for VB.NET, causes autoinserting of ByVal in front of all the parameters which have it implicitly.

This is an issue since, working on a big project, when we need to review the code, all this non-changes are highlited in the comparison with the version control base.

Is there any way to have "Pretty listing" to continue formatting the code, but not to touch the rest of the code or not to force explicit ByVal?

(We also use ReSharper, in case this might have some functionality to resolve this issue)

Cannot update to SP1 as it's not been approved on the internal software centre.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer is you can't avoid the insertion of ByVal without either turning off Pretty Listing, or upgrading to a more recent version of Visual Studio.

As a workaround, perhaps you can create a version of the unmodified code that has had Pretty Listing applied to it (e.g. cut and paste the entire code) and compare the modified code to that.